# Plot Satellite data (.nc format) in ggplot with higher resolution and adding colour bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, satellite, ncdf4

I would like to plot satellite chlorophyll of a region set by coordinates. However the resolution seems to be very low, (a lot of big blocks/pixels). And

I would like to:

- Extrapolate or smooth the data so the blocks are smaller.
- Plot values in log scale because the gradient is very small (0.01-0.5 units)
- Make the colour bar appear, which is not.

I am using the raster package following [this tutorial](https://semba-blog.netlify.app/12/01/2019/plotting-the-spatial-distribution-of-chlorophyll-from-modis/) although they have alternative packages: ncdf4 and ocean map

The nc file (it's 16kb) can be found [here](https://fastupload.io/vjy2uPDNJd09piU/file)

```
require(oceanmap)
require(raster)
require(ncdf4)
require(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)

# Plot of the desired area without chl
  ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-22, -12), ylim = c(24, 29), expand = FALSE)

 
chl.a = raster::raster("~/Downloads/file_chl_satellite.nc", 
                       varname = "chl")  ## read as raster object

rufiji.extent = raster::extent(-21.75, -13, 24, 29) ## create chopping object

chl.a = raster::crop(x = chl.a, y = rufiji.extent) ## chop the raster object

# assign all cells with values between 0.01 and 0.5
chl.a = chl.a %>% 
  raster::clamp(upper = 0.5, # upper clamp value
                lower = 0.01,  # lower clamp value
                usevalues = FALSE # force value to NA
  )

## convert from raster object to data frame and then tibble
chl.a.tb = chl.a %>% 
  raster::as.data.frame(xy = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(lon = 1, lat = 2, chl = 3) %>%
  mutate(chl_log = log(chl + 1))  # Convert to log scale

## map the distribution of chl
ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data = chl.a.tb, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = chl_log)) +
  geom_sf(data = world, fill = "grey80", col = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-21, -13), c(24.2, 28.5)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = oce::oce.colorsJet(120), 
                       na.value = "white", 
                       breaks = seq(0, log(4.2 + 1), 0.5), 
                       labels = scales::number_format(scale = 1)) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = expression(log(Chlorophyll_a + 1))),
         title.position = "right",
         title.theme = element_text(angle = 90), 
         barwidth = unit(.5, "cm"), barheight = unit(7.5, "cm"), title.hjust = .5) +
  theme_bw()
```

**THIS IS THE CURRENT OUTPUT:**
[image: Plot with too many pixels]

**THIS IS MY DESIRED OUTPUT:** with higher resolution, log scale values and bar as legend.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here some hints using `terra` package (`raster` is now deprecated).

Border values (holes and boundaries) won't be interpolated because of NA's (in your desired plot it's assumed that they are zeroes!)

I did not put the rest of your code (for cropping and plot format) as it is basically the same.

- `terra::disagg` function is a simple resampling function for integer scale factor.
- `tidyterra` has convenient functions to help plot terra rasters (it does the same as `as.data.frame(xy=TRUE))`

```
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

# load original raster
test <- terra::rast("file_chl_satellite.nc")

# supersample by a factor of 4
test <- terra::disagg(test, 4, method="bilinear")

# clamp values
test <- terra::clamp(test, lower=0.01, upper=0.5, values=FALSE)

# rescale values
test <- log(test+1)

# rename layer (easier for setting fill aes)
names(test) <- "Chl"

# build plot
ggplot()+
  tidyterra::geom_spatraster(
    aes(fill=Chl), 
    data=test, 
    interpolate=TRUE # if you want further interpolation
  )+
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = oce::oce.colorsJet(120),
    breaks = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
    limits = c(0.1, 0.5)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  guides(
    fill = guide_colorbar(
      title = expression(log(Chlorophyll_a + 1)), 
      title.position = "bottom", 
      barwidth = unit(10, "cm"), 
      barheight = unit(.5, "cm"),
      title.hjust = .5,
      frame.colour="black",
      ticks.colour="black"
    )
  )
```

Comment: Perfect this is much better, thanks!! but the colour bar still does not show. Do you know why? Seems to ignore this: ` +guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = expression(log(Chlorophyll_a + 1))), title.position = "right", title.theme = element_text(angle = 90), barwidth = unit(.5, "cm"), barheight = unit(7.5, "cm"), title.hjust = .5)`

Comment: Updated my answer with legend